# classes autoload in a site when user come not to index.php

Tags: php, autoload

In the simple case I have a site with some pages: *index.php*, *registration.php*, *order.php*, *product-page.php*, etc. So, also I have.. maybe, *logging_class.php*. I wrote class autoload function in index.php like this:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) { 
     return require_once $className . ".php";
});
```

And that's why I think all scripts after index.php will include classes (in that case it's *logging_class.php*) automatically. But if user come to my site from google to the product page bypassing the main page that *index.php* isn't executed. So, *product-page.php* knows nothing about class autoload.

It's not correct way to write the same function in every script. Maybe, it's correct to write *autoload.php* and include it in any script where I need to use a class. But I'll have a lot of include-strings in different parts of my project.

So, is there way to make automatically executing of *index.php* in the server scripts not including *autoload.php* in every script?

Comment: Sure, you can route all the traffic to your index.php but then you have to make a PHP router. So you have the following choices: a) Include autoload.php in every script or b) make a PHP router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple entry points to your website (index.php, registration.php, order.php, product-page.php, etc.), the best solution is to create that "autoload.php" and include it everywhere, just like you wrote.

There are other solutions, like [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) - but they make your solution less "readable" (personal opinion).

Also, maybe it would be a good idea not to name it "autoload.php", but something like "common.php" or "bootstrap.php", because it is highly probable that it will also include other common code, not just the autoloader.